# Access Parent Window UI from Child Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I have a `Page` that is loaded inside a `Window`. When the user logs in I would like to show an `Image` in the `Window`, the Login method is however within the `Page`. I'm trying to call a method inside the `Window`, which is working for displaying a `MessageBox` but not displaying the `Image`. Here is some code;

**MainWindow**

```
public void initUI()
{
    navigationFrame.Navigate(new Uri("View/MainPages/LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}

public void ShowSDCImage()
{
    sdcLogo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    MessageBox.Show("Test"); // This is displayed
}
```

**ChildPage**

```
private void EnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        if (UserAuthenticationService.AuthenticateUser(passwordBox.Password))
        {
            var lGs = new LoginService();
            var sqlServerCheck = new MySQLServerCheck();
            if (sqlServerCheck.ServerIsOnline())
            {
                MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
                mw.ShowSDCImage();                    
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("View/MainPages/DashboardPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the server is offline. Please notify IT.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password");
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the MainWindow I am trying to use

`MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
 mw.ShowSDCImage();`

and although this would display the `MessageBox`, it does not display the `Image`. What am I doing wrong and how can I successfully access the MainWindow's `Image`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MainWindow W;

private void EnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        if (UserAuthenticationService.AuthenticateUser(passwordBox.Password))
        {
            var lGs = new LoginService();
            var sqlServerCheck = new MySQLServerCheck();
            if (sqlServerCheck.ServerIsOnline())
            {
                W.ShowSDCImage();                    
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("View/MainPages/DashboardPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the server is offline. Please notify IT.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password");
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Use:

```
// Call this in your MainWindow() code:
public MainWindow()
{
    yourClassHere.W = this;
}
```

Comment: The Issue i have with this is that I don't create a new ChildPage. I use a `NavigationFrame` and simply navigate to it.

Comment: Can you call directly `ShowSDCImage(); ` instead of `mw.ShowSDCImage(); `?

Comment: Still not working and I'm not keen on using Static variables, there must be a better way

Comment: Ok. is `EnterPressed` and `MainWindow` belong to same class or not?

Comment: `EnterPressed` is in the `ChildPage`, `MainWindow` is the `ParentWindow`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104275/discussion-between-sakura-and-cbreeze).

Comment: then how you call `ChildPage()` function?

Comment: AS I said before it's navigated to in a `NavgiationFrame`, it doesn't need to be called like you are saying here.

Comment: I understand, but do you have `class ChildPage` somewhere? note I ask about `class`, not `control`. If you don't have, then you dont have `ChildPage` class.